# how to deploy a Hapi.js API to AWS Lambda and API gateway?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, hapi.js

I developed a hapi App using Node.js and i want to deploy it as a Lambda and will be accessible through API gateway. I did this multiple times but with express based application (mostly using claudia.js) and i couldn't find any documentations showing how to do this with hapi.

Can anyone point me to the right direction of how to achieve this ? thanks in advance

Comment: lalalambda is kind of the Claudia.js for hapi. https://github.com/hapipal/lalalambda

Answer (score 0):

The `hapi-lambda` package worked for me.

Ensure you serverless path to the handler is {proxy+} and use the following:

```
const api = require('./api');
const { transformRequest, transformResponse } = require('hapi-lambda');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const server = await api.init();

  const request = transformRequest(event);
  const response = await server.inject(request);
  return transformResponse(response);
};
```

Taken off the website of the package developer:
https://www.carbonatethis.com/hosting-a-serverless-hapi-17-api-with-aws-lambda/